# Is there any survey of dg-categories from the $\infty$-category point of view?

Tags: reference-request, infinity-categories, dg-categories

I was reading [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/242460/dg-categories-in-algebraic-geometry-guide-to-the-literature/242842) on dg-categories and a comment by David Ben-Zvi says "An excellent pre-$\infty$-categorical overview is Keller's ICM address https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0601185".

I was aware of Keller's ICM address before, but this made me think, now that 12 years passed, is there any survey from the $\infty$-category point of view? To be precise, by $\infty$-category I mean $(\infty,1)$-categories.

Comment: Maybe some of Gaitsgory's notes at http://www.math.harvard.edu/~gaitsgde/GL/ ?

Comment: Oops -- that's already referenced in the original question.